# Why did the logo not loading even the direct access working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, path

I have one template & i used base_url() to load the logo. In source the path can be accessible but the logo is not loading into the webpage ?

```
  <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/frontend/img/logos/logo.png'); ?>" alt="logo">
                </a>
```

When i use without logo class its working

```
  <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/frontend/img/logos/logo.png'); ?>" alt="logo">
```

How i can load the logo within logo class ?

Comment: May be some `CSS` is applying on class `logo`.

Comment: Yea it got worked when i directly included into the template page instead of loading it from style.css